# Type error: Property 'getJSON' does not exist on type 'typeof import("js-cookie")'

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jquery-cookie, js-cookie, react-cookie

I'm unable to build the following JS react code:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

React.useEffect(() => {
  
  interface UserInfo {
  name: string;
  verified: boolean;
}
  
  const userInfo = Cookies.getJSON('userInfo');
  if (userInfo && !userInfo.verified) {
    setUserName(`unknown`);
  } else {
    setUserName('else');
  }
}, []);
```

First, I tried `npm install --save @types/js-cookie`
When I kept getting the error, I created `js-cookie.d.ts` with this content:

```
declare module 'js-cookie' {
  interface CookiesStatic<T extends string | undefined = undefined> {
    getJSON(key: string): T extends undefined ? any : T;
  }
}
```

and placed it under `/app/node_modules/@types/js-cookie`

Then I also created types folder and place that file there:

`/app/src/types/js-cookie.d.ts`

And I edited `/app/tsconfig.ts`

And added the lines:

"types": ["node", "react", "@types/js-cookie"],
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "./src/types"]

nothing worked, still getting same error. how to debug?

Comment: Can you try `const userInfo = Cookies.get('userInfo');`

Comment: I don't see `getJSON` in the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie

Comment: @RohitKhanna it returns `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'typeof import("js-cookie")'.`. Also, the info in the cookie is encoded in json format like `%7B%22name%22%3A%22John+D%22%2C%22verified%22%3A1%7D` so I need a way to decode it, that's why I try GetJSON

Comment: @Konrad thanks, not sure why it got into my code. I'm confused though since even `.get` doesn't seem to work right now.

Comment: I opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869976/type-error-property-get-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-importjs-cookie