# Type error: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'typeof import("js-cookie")'

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jquery-cookie, js-cookie, react-cookie

I'm unable to build the following JS react code:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

React.useEffect(() => {
  
  interface UserInfo {
  name: string;
  verified: boolean;
}
  
  const userInfo = Cookies.get('userInfo');
  if (userInfo && !userInfo.verified) {
    setUserName(`unknown`);
  } else {
    setUserName('else');
  }
}, []);
```

Getting:

> Type error: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'typeof
> import("js-cookie")'.
>
> > 87 |   const userInfo =  Cookies.get('userInfo');

I tried:
`npm install js-cookie`
`npm install --save @types/js-cookie`

but still getting the error, any idea why?

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-kare-ymvl54?file=/src/App.tsx:274-397

Comment: @Konrad any idea what might be wrong on my end? :/

Comment: @Konrad seems to work now, maybe i had some leftover file which disrupted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through [the type definitions for `js-cookie`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/js-cookie/index.d.ts) I found an odd bit of syntax: `export = Cookies`.

We're far away from an `export default Cookies`.

So why this syntax? Well according to [this (still open) issue on Typescript Github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/js-cookie/index.d.ts) it means the module was authored using Node's CommonJS syntax (i.e. `require` and `module.exports`) but here's the catch, `js-cookie` (at least on its main branch) is authored using good old ES6 modules using the `.mjs` extension, and it does use an `export default` statement.

So what happened? It could be one of the following:

- Previous versions weren't written using modules and the type definitions have not been updated since
- Their rollup config does something very strange in its bundling

My potential fixes (sorted from preferred to least preferred):

- Use `import * as Cookies from "js-cookie"` and see if it functions properly
- Use `import { default as Cookies } from "js-cookie"` and see if it functions properly
- Use the ugly but apparently valid syntax of `import Cookies = require("js-cookie")`

If none function properly in your app, then we'll need to dig into TS usage of js-cookie to find what works for them